# 2 columns text and image padding issue

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website design for fun and I encountered annoying problem with 2 columns which include image and text. They are set to 50% width and everything is responsive but the problem is text column looks bad because it doesn't have any padding.

After adding padding to text column, image column has some weird spacing. It doesn't work for me to add padding to both columns because I want image to take full size of container.

I want image to be full height without no padding in it's container and I want text to have padding so it looks better. But after doing that there is that gray space below image as seen in first picture. It would be nice to have text centered vertically and horizontally

[image]

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.slidershow {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
}

.leftcolumn_slider {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10%;
}

.rightcolumn_slider {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.slidershow img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidershow">
  <div class="leftcolumn_slider">
    <h1>INTERNETAS NAMAMS</h1>
    <p>Telia profesionalų komanda, prižiūrinti ryšio kokybę ir 24 val. pasiruošusi išspręsti bet kurią jums kilusią problemą, – geriausia interneto garantija.
    </p>
    <p>Išbandykite net 30 d. nemokamai ir įsitikinkite</p>
    <button>Plačiau</button>
  </div>
  <div class="rightcolumn_slider">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2017/09/12/11/naturo-monkey-selfie.jpg?w968">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://secure.i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03013/selfie02_3013424b.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.hindustantimes.com/rf/image_size_960x540/HT/p2/2017/12/06/Pictures/monkey-selfie_e5db3572-da5a-11e7-ad52-47d546f3ccd3.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect for text column to have padding and image to be full stretched to it's container but image quality should remain

[image]

Comment: You have set the image width to 100%, this will mean the image will drop in quality when it's stretched past it's natural size. `img { max-width: 100%}` will resolve any "quality" issues.

Comment: @jnowland I still see the same result as in picture above. As I said, I don't want to add padding to both containers

Comment: I'm still not clear what you're looking for. Could you please explain in a different way.

Comment: Sure, please see the last picture. I would like columns to look like that, but text to have some padding so its' not touching borders and image is full streched. This picture is after removing padding from left column

Comment: I still not clear what you're looking for. Could you speak in detail ?

Comment: @Adomas you want to make the text column center based img column height?

Comment: Adomas, You are adding padding to the top, left, bottom, and right in the first image and no padding on the second. Are you wanting to get ride of the padding on the bottom and center the text vertically?

Comment: I want image to be full height without no padding in it's container and I want text to have padding so it looks better. But after doing that there is that gray space below image as seen in first picture. @Wayne, would be nice to have text centered vertically and horizontally

Comment: @Saravana, yes exactly

Comment: @Adomas, updated your question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the `display:block` for your image class to remove the white space because `img` is an inline element by default.

To make the left column center add `display:flex` for parent class and add `align-self:center` for left column to align center.

```css
* {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.slidershow {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
    display: flex;
}

.leftcolumn_slider {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10%;
    align-self:center;
}

.rightcolumn_slider {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}

.slidershow img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px 50%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px 50%;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover
}
```

```html
<div class="slidershow">
    <div class="leftcolumn_slider">
        <h1>INTERNETAS NAMAMS</h1>
        <p>Telia profesionalų komanda, prižiūrinti ryšio kokybę ir 24 val. pasiruošusi išspręsti bet kurią jums kilusią problemą, – geriausia interneto garantija.
        </p>
        <p>Išbandykite net 30 d. nemokamai ir įsitikinkite</p>
        <button>Plačiau</button>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn_slider">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2017/09/12/11/naturo-monkey-selfie.jpg?w968">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have a gray space below image

Comment: Yes, looks like this https://postimg.cc/xXbnm2tC. I don't want that space below image

Comment: Looks much better! Is it because of object-fit: cover? Only one thing, it get's a bit of empty space when sized to mobile screen size, but I guess that is solved with media queries? Will make your comment as answer

Comment: Noted. Yes for mobile you can use media queries.

Answer (score 3):

### **EDIT:**

**ADDED MEDIA QUERY TO SOLVE THE ISSUE**

Create a div inside of class `leftcolumn_slider`, and give that div padding of suitable padding value.

> **Issues** -  If the image is full width and text is larger

[image]

```css
.solution {
  padding: 10%;
}

* {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.slidershow {
  display: flex;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
}

.leftcolumn_slider h1,
.leftcolumn_slider p {
  font-size: 100%;
}

.leftcolumn_slider {
  width: 50%;
}

.rightcolumn_slider {
  width: 50%;
}

.slidershow img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .slidershow {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  .leftcolumn_slider,
  .rightcolumn_slider {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .slidershow img {
    border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slidershow">
  <div class="leftcolumn_slider">
    <div class="solution">
      <h1>INTERNETAS NAMAMS</h1>
      <p>Telia profesionalų komanda, prižiūrinti ryšio kokybę ir 24 val. pasiruošusi išspręsti bet kurią jums kilusią problemą, – geriausia interneto garantija.
      </p>
      <p>Išbandykite net 30 d. nemokamai ir įsitikinkite</p>
      <button>Plačiau</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightcolumn_slider">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2017/09/12/11/naturo-monkey-selfie.jpg?w968">
    <!--         <img class="mySlides" src="https://secure.i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03013/selfie02_3013424b.jpg" >
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.hindustantimes.com/rf/image_size_960x540/HT/p2/2017/12/06/Pictures/monkey-selfie_e5db3572-da5a-11e7-ad52-47d546f3ccd3.jpg" > -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks better but space is still below image when resizing browser window. Do you know how to get rid of that? Also, is using display:flex only solution here, is is not possible to do this with floats?

Comment: You are going to need to scale down the size of the text for smaller view areas. The text you are using in the html example is bigger than the text you are using in the photo examples.

Comment: you will get the space below the image if the text is larger than the image, it usually happens for screen-size less than 768px. And in those scenarios, you will need to use things in the way it's done above.

Comment: @Wayne, photo example is just a snapshot of a small portion of the screen. size of text isn't accurate or even near to the actual one in the code.

Comment: Already found a solution, but will definitely try yours with added comments. Thanks a lot!

Comment: add rule for media screen @media only screen and (max-width: 768px)  {.leftcolumn_slider {size zoom: 0.5  -moz-transform: scale(0.5);}} will not be able to validate the size within run code snppet on this site.

Comment: @Wayne, please feel free to edit the answer to enhance it.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh Your last edit seems to be working well, the choice between a larger image with same size text or same size image with smaller text is aesthetics, and what is readable on cell phones.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh clearly there is not enough space for the text in portrait mode on a cell phone for the text to be 50% and legible, likely at that point your solution is the only one left for readability. Maybe scale-able for landscape?

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.slidershow {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
  display: flex;
}

.leftcolumn_slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1.5%
}
button{
  align-self: center;
}
p{
  align-self: center;
}

.rightcolumn_slider {
display: flex;
}
.mySlides{
  display:flex;
}

.mySlides img{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slidershow img {
  border-top-left-radius: 50px 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidershow">
  <div class="leftcolumn_slider">
    <h1>INTERNETAS NAMAMS</h1>
    <p>Telia profesionalų komanda, prižiūrinti ryšio kokybę ir 24 val. pasiruošusi išspręsti bet kurią jums kilusią problemą, – geriausia interneto garantija.
    </p>
    <p>Išbandykite net 30 d. nemokamai ir įsitikinkite</p>
    <button>Plačiau</button>
  </div>
  <div class="rightcolumn_slider">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2017/09/12/11/naturo-monkey-selfie.jpg?w968">
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this.